# Pdo passsa retorno vaizio em JSON

Tags: php, json, pdo

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de fluxo de caixa com entrada e saída, porem, quando o valor JSON está retornando vazio.
segue abaixo o código

PHP

```
$ano_hoje = date('Y');

$janeiro_entrada = $conexao->query("SELECT SUM(entrada) AS total FROM caixa where  month(data_trans) ='01' AND YEAR(data_trans)='.$ano_hoje.'");
 while ($row=$janeiro_entrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);
        $json2[]= (int)$row;
 }
```

JS

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [<?php echo json_encode($json2); ?>],
        label: "Entrada",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [],
        label: "Saída",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, 
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Fechamento mensal referente ao ano atual'
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

No PHP você pode usar o `fetchAll` passando `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` para receber um array associativo e depois codificar no formato json:

```
$ano_hoje = date('Y');

$janeiro_entrada = $conexao->query("SELECT SUM(entrada) AS total FROM caixa where  month(data_trans) ='01' AND YEAR(data_trans)='$ano_hoje'");

$data = $janeiro_entrada->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas o valor não está parecendo no grafico.
O valor que retorno é este [{total:2000}]

Comment: No JS do char troque `data: [<?php echo json_encode($json2); ?>]` por `data: <?php echo $json; ?>`

Comment: Sim, realizei está operação. Mas mesmo  assim no Gráfico não aparece o valor

Comment: Parece que o problema é outro, sugiro abrir outra pergunta específica para esse problema. Deve ser algo relacionado a biblioteca do chart

Comment: Beleza, obrigado amigo !